# Autologin after hibernation but not after sleep in linux

Tags: linux, passwords, sleep, hibernate

I would like to set my computer to require a password after waking up from sleep but not to require a password after resuming from hibernation.

The reason is that my disk is encrypted and hence, after hibernation I need to input two passwords which is not desired. On the other hand I want to keep the password when waking up from sleep.

I am only able to enable or disable both sleep/hibernation password together.

I am using Debian linux (Bullseye) with KDE desktop and SDDM as display manager.

Is it possible to accomplish this? How?

Comment: I have the same problem on Kubuntu (KDE Plasma 5 on Ubuntu). I might just never use sleep..